# Python-odd,even number

Tags: python

I have a problem. I must write a boolean function `isOdd()` that will return true if its number parameter is an odd number. For example,I will call `OddNumber(4)` then it will return it's odd or not. It'll be boolean it must return true or false.

Here's what I have tried:

```
def OddNumber(number): 
    def isodd(): 
        if number%2==0: 
            return False 
        if number%2!=0: 
            return True 

print OddNumber(51)
```

Comment: def OddNumber(number):
  def isodd():
    if number%2==0:
      return False
   
    if number%2!=0:
      return True

print OddNumber(51)

Comment: Why do you have a nested function? There's no need for that here. It's also the cause of your problem: `OddNumber` doesn't actually _do_ anything. Take out the nested function definition.

Comment: My teacher wants an extra method from me called isodd().

Comment: Your teacher wants both `OddNumber` _and_ `isodd`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: it's quite easy - you use a modulo operator, it will return false or true.

```
def OddNumber(number):
    return number % 2 == 1
```

Comment: Updated code, mistyped 0 instead of 1.

Comment: The OP is already using `%`, so the explanation is useless. It doesn't address anything about why their code isn't working. And, of course, this strategy is already available in the linked duplicate. This answer adds nothing of value.

Comment: I must call like OddNumber(7).

Comment: Then change the function to 'OddNumber'

Comment: Updated function name, now you can call OddNumber(7) and it will return true.

Comment: The OP is supposed to be using two functions, as clarified in comments on the question.